# if option-text isn't CSS then select it

Tags: jquery, html-select

```
$("select[name=lang] > option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "CSS"){
        $("select[name=lang]").val($(this).val());
    }
}

<select name=lang>
<option value=0>Select
<option value=1>HTML
<option value=2>CSS
<option value=3>PHP
</select>
```

i want to check all options and select by optiontext.
best regards

Comment: can you give us a better description of what is going wrong? What do you actually want to do?

Comment: **If** you wan to select the option with text 'CSS' (which I conclude from your code although your question states otherwise), with proper HTML markup (attributes in quotes, closing `option` tags), your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/sSRDR/

Comment: Felix, should put that as an answer, works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you want to select the option with text 'CSS' (which I conclude from your code although your question states otherwise), with proper HTML markup

```
<select name="lang">
    <option value=0>Select</option>
    <option value=1>HTML</option>
    <option value=2>CSS</option>
    <option value=3>PHP</option>
</select>
```

your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/sSRDR/

Proper markup in this case means:

- attributes in quotes
- closing `option` tags

Normally you don't have to have closing tags (although there is no reason to not have them), the browser will insert them for you, but in this case if you don't put them, the browser will generate

```
<option value=2>CSS
</option>
```

which means the text inside the option is `"CSS\n"` (`CSS` + line break) and this will never be equal to solely `"CSS"`.

However, if you can exclude that the text you are searching for can occur in other elements, you can use [**`:contains()`**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('option:contains(CSS)').attr('selected', true);
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to select everything that is not "CSS", then you need a multiple `select` box, as a normal `select` can only have one selected option:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="lang">
```

and you can use [**`.filter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out the options:

```
$('select[name="lang"] > option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() !== "CSS";
}).attr('selected', true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/sSRDR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[name=lang] > option").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).text() == "CSS"){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work. `each` is not an event handler, i.e. there is no `event.target`.

Comment: i want to read all optiontext onload and if the text ins't CSS, then select this. without click or or other events. thx muhammad

Comment: @StevenMoss: So you want to select everything that **is not** CSS? Your code is doing something different. By default you can only select one option. Do you want to have a multiple select box?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/sSRDR/ works fine but not http://tinyurl.com/select-this

Comment: @StevenMoss: Read my answer again and compare it to your code. Then you should know why it does not work.

Comment: @Felix: am i blind or can't i see any difference?

Comment: @StevenMoss: Hint: HTML markup. I also revised my answer and provided some more information.

Comment: @StevenMoss: You're welcome :) Btw. if your question is solved, you should mark the answer that helped you the most by clicking the tick outline next to it.